# Multiple attachment django email

Tags: django

Hi i'm try send email with multiple attach as pdf, xml.etc... but get error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

this is my code:

```
from security.views import SendEmail

Envia = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
files =['media/Facturas/facturaElectronica.pdf', 'media/Facturas/template/factura.xml']
SendEmail('test', 'Test ',Envia,['pocholo199037@gmail.com'],files)
```

on the security.views is this code:

```
def SendEmail( Asunto, Mensaje, Envia, Destinatarios, Adjunto1 ):

    """Permite el Envio de Correo con/sin adjunto """
    #importamos configuraciones
    from django.conf import settings
    Envia = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

    email = EmailMessage(
        Asunto,
        Mensaje,
        Envia,
        Destinatarios
    )
    email.attach_file(Adjunto1)
```

i don't understand why get this error maybe some one idea or suggest , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a list as an attachment....

Loop through the files before attaching:

```
def SendEmail( Asunto, Mensaje, Envia, Destinatarios, Adjunto1 ):
    """Permite el Envio de Correo con/sin adjunto """
    #importamos configuraciones
    from django.conf import settings
    Envia = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

    email = EmailMessage(
    Asunto,
    Mensaje,
    Envia,
    Destinatarios
)

    for file in Adjunto1:
        email.attach_file(file)
```