# Attach Multiple PDF files in email attachment using Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use django's core emailing functionality but for some reason I cant seem to find a way to attach 2 files in one email. I have tried to put the files in an array but this throws an error. Sending one file works but as soon as i create an array it stops working. Below are the steps I have taken. In my views.py i have

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
```

and below is the part I am trying to send the 2 email attachments.

```
msg = EmailMessage('Email Subject', 'Test Email',
                           'from@email.com', ['test@gmail.com'])
        msg.content_subtype = "html"
        msg.attach_file(['product/y.pdf', 'product/x.pdf'])
        msg.send()
```

Please help.

Comment: [This is the solution for your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53382668/multiple-attachment-django-email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must attach each item separately:

```
msg = EmailMessage('Email Subject', 'Test Email',
                           'from@email.com', ['test@gmail.com'])
msg.content_subtype = "html"
files_to_attach = ['product/y.pdf', 'product/x.pdf']
for file_to_attach in files_to_attach:
    msg.attach_file(file_to_attach)
msg.send()
```

Simple as that.

Comment: You simply the best. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you