# Multiple Files In Email Django

Tags: python, django

I have a list of files, each with its own checkbox.  I then get a list of all of the items where the checkbox is marked.  I would like for these files to be passed to my view and to be automatically attached.

Here is the view which shows the list of files:

```
def DocListView(request, pk):

    if request.method == "POST":
        documents = request.POST.getlist('checks')


    else:
        return render(request, 'doc_list.html', context)
```

doc_list.html

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-group">
      {% for item in PackingListDocs %}
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="{% url 'EditPackingListView' item.Packing_List.pk %}" class="a" type="button">
            <div class="md-v-line"></div><input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="{{ item.PackingListDocument.url|default_if_none:'#' }}">{{item.Packing_List.Name}}<a class="doclink" href="{{ item.PackingListDocument.url|default_if_none:'#' }}" download>View Doc</a>
        </a>
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

So as you can see I get a list ```documents = request.POST.getlist('checks').  Now my next view currently looks like this.

```
def email(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmailForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
          # post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            subject = request.POST.get('subject')
            message = request.POST.get('message')
            document = request.FILES.get('document')
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            recipient_list = [email]
            email = EmailMessage(subject,message,email_from,recipient_list)
            base_dir = 'media'
            email.attach_file('Poseidon/media/media/'+str(document))
            email.send()
            return redirect('HomeView')
    else:
        form = EmailForm()
        return render(request, 'docemail.html', {'form': form})
```

It works fine, but it makes the user choose a file to upload, and I can only upload one per email...so how could I amend this view in order to get each item within my `documents` list and attach it to my email?

Comment: did you try to use `attach_file()` many times - to attache many files (every file attached separatelly) ?

Comment: found with Google `"django email many attachments"`: [Multiple attachment django email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53382668/multiple-attachment-django-email).

Comment: @furas I read through that, but how would I have to document attached when my view loads.  As in when the ```email``` view renders, each of these documents should already be attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a good approach to this would be to pass an array of file objects to the `def email()` view and then loop through them with email.attach_file

Something like this:

```
def email(request, docs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmailForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
          # post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            subject = request.POST.get('subject')
            message = request.POST.get('message')
            document = request.FILES.get('document')
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            recipient_list = [email]
            email = EmailMessage(subject,message,email_from,recipient_list)
            base_dir = 'media'
            if docs:
                for doc in docs:
                    email.attach_file('Poseidon/media/media/'+str(doc))
            email.send()
            return redirect('HomeView')
    else:
        form = EmailForm()
        return render(request, 'docemail.html', {'form': form, 'docs': docs})
```